# Save form data for re-visit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with the following radio options in a form. I want to save the data that someone submits so that the next time they visit, that option is selected by default. I am using a django backend, but I would prefer to do this with javascript.

```
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="scoring" id="standard" value="standard" checked> Standard
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="scoring" id="decimal" value="decimal"> Decimal
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="scoring" id="standard_ppr" value="standard_ppr"> Standard PPR
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="scoring" id="decimal_ppr" value="decimal_ppr"> Decimal PPR
            </label>
```

Comment: [Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  The first is with cookies, check out this little tutorial on [cookies in django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/cookie.html).  Basically what you would do here is save the cookie and have django print whatever they selected last time as having a `checked` attribute.  The other way to do this is, if you have a login system store their selection in your database, and once again print the `checked` attribute on their previous selection.

You did mention you wanted to do this in javascript, if you want you can do that with code like this `document.cookie="username=John Doe";` (from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) tutorial).  Then using javascript, you can check the value of the cookie and make whatever the value of the cookie is there selection.  Good Luck!